# Chart.js yAxes Ticks stepSize not working (fiddle)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have created a line chart with these options for the yAxis:

```
yAxes: [{
    ticks: {
        precision: 1,
        stepSize: 18.1,
        min: 148.5,
        max: 220.9
    }
}]
```

I would like, therefore, the yAxis scales to be like this:

```
220.9
202.8
184.7
166.6
148.5
```

However, when I provide this code, I am getting this data.

[image]

Please see this fiddle for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/wxLzdrcm/

How can I make the yAxis ticks add up like I have described?

Comment: The issue I see is your stepSize is not consistent with max and min, that's why you are seeing some clip at the top, try `suggestedMin` & `suggestedMax` though with this stepSize won't be effective so you need to choose between any of those

`the min and max settings set explicit ends to the axes. When these are set, some data points may not be visible.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was asked at least twice ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427649/chart-js-stepsize-not-working-with-min), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47334236/how-to-set-axes-step-size-in-chart-js-2)).

The solution is to use `min` and `max` values so that `stepSize` is a factor of `max - min`, allowing the chart to actually use the specified `stepSize`:

```
yAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    maxTicksLimit: 5,
    min: 144.8, // 18.1 * 8
    max: 235.3, // 18.1 * 13
    stepSize: 18.1,
  },
}]
```

[image]

---

An alternative would be using `suggestedMin` and `suggestedMax` rather than `min` and `max`, which allows Chart.js to calculate its own `min` and `max`:

In your case, you just need to apply:

```
yAxes: [{
  ticks: {
    maxTicksLimit: 5,
    suggestedMin: 148.5,
    suggestedMax: 220.9,
    stepSize: 18.1,
  },
}]
```

Comment: I had researched many questions before posting, and definitely tried some things that had helped get to this point so far -- however, I have missed the point that was described in your first SO link about how the stepSize needs to divide cleanly into the increments. Our native applications are able to use the same data, and show it fine; but it doesn't seem like an out-of-the-box solution will work from chart.js with a non-cleanly divisible stepSize

Comment: I totally agree this is a non-intuitive behaviour of Chart.js